# Get percentual of memory usage across all namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I have this query:

```
100 * (1 - ((avg_over_time(node_memory_MemFree_bytes[10m]) + avg_over_time(node_memory_Cached_bytes[10m]) + avg_over_time(node_memory_Buffers_bytes[10m])) / avg_over_time(node_memory_MemTotal_bytes[10m])))
```

However it only returns the namespace where Prometheus is installed:

```
{instance="10.240.0.11:9100", job="kubernetes-service-endpoints", kubernetes_name="node-exporter", kubernetes_namespace="monitoring"}
5.58905365516873
{instance="10.240.0.11:9100", job="node-exporter"}
5.588556605118522
{instance="10.240.0.42:9100", job="kubernetes-service-endpoints", kubernetes_name="node-exporter", kubernetes_namespace="monitoring"}
5.093870850709847
{instance="10.240.0.42:9100", job="node-exporter"}
5.09401539556571
{instance="10.240.0.90:9100", job="kubernetes-service-endpoints", kubernetes_name="node-exporter", kubernetes_namespace="monitoring"}
5.103046564234582
{instance="10.240.0.90:9100", job="node-exporter"}
```

Is it possible to have a similar query that queries the entire cluster, all nodes and namespaces? If yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the node-exporter installed as daemonset, you have the metrics of the entire cluster.

To have the overall cluster memory usage, in percentage:

```
100 * (
 sum(node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{service="node-exporter"}) -
 sum(node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes{service="node-exporter"})
) / sum(node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{service="node-exporter"})
```

Result, for example:

```
{}   37.234674067149946
```

Memory usage by node:

```
100 * (
 sum by (instance) (node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{service="node-exporter"}) - 
 sum by (instance) (node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes{service="node-exporter"})
) / sum by (instance) (node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{service="node-exporter"})
```

Result, for example:

```
{instance="x.x.x.x:9100"}   42.51742364002058
{instance="y.y.y.y:9100"}   38.26956501095188
{instance="z.z.z.z:9100"}   36.57150031634585
```

Memory usage for a specific namespace:

```
100 * sum(container_memory_working_set_bytes{namespace="my-namespace"}) / 
sum(node_memory_MemTotal_bytes)
```

Result, for example:

```
{} 4.212481093513011
```